# IllegalStateException when updating adapter data

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-adapter

Please, help me to find a fix for this bug, where it appears in the production version and I don't know where is the bug exactly from the following log.

I got the following log report from Crashlytics:

```
ListView.java line 1557
android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren 

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the 
adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure 
the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but 
only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131558802, class 
android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class 
android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1557)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3442)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7565)
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: Maybe you have missed to notify data changed `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the data from the main thread.

If you are getting data in a background thread, either wait for the result in the main thread, change the data, and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), or go back to the main thread from your background thread using a handler and a run() method.